Why does my create mutation return null for a subtype using AWS Amplify AppSync?
I have the following type:
type Transplant @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner }]) {
    id: ID!
    date: AWSDateTime!
    plant: Plant! @hasOne
    plantingBed: PlantingBed! @hasOne
    variety: Variety @hasOne
    numberOfSeedlings: Int!
    comment: String
}

When I try to create a new Transplant I am getting a result of

"Cannot return null for non-nullable type: 'ID' within parent 'Variety' (/createTransplant/variety/id)"

This is my mutation:
mutation MyMutation {
  createTransplant(input: {numberOfSeedlings: 22, transplantPlantId: "d108d-a6f3-024e-c281-5affed45fb1", transplantPlantingBedId: "d108d-a6f3-024e-c281-5affed45fb1", transplantVarietyId: "d108d-a6f3-024e-c281-5affed45fb1", date: "2024-07-20T00:00:00.000Z"}) {
    variety {
      id
      name
      plant
    }
    id
    date
    plant {
      name
    }
    numberOfSeedlings
    variety {
      name
    }
  }
}

The plant and plantingBed come back with no issues, just not the variety.
My understanding is that this may be due to a resolver not returning the data, but that should be set up via Amplify (or I would have thought)
.
This is the result of the mutation:
{
  "data": {
    "createTransplant": {
      "variety": null,
      "id": "fd00df12-7370-4016-a575-6bd21ce8f8f1",
      "date": "2024-07-20T00:00:00.000Z",
      "plant": {
        "name": "Bush Beans"
      },
      "numberOfSeedlings": 22
    }
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "path": [
        "createTransplant",
        "variety",
        "id"
      ],
      "locations": null,
      "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable type: 'ID' within parent 'Variety' (/createTransplant/variety/id)"
    },
    {
      "path": [
        "createTransplant",
        "variety",
        "name"
      ],
      "locations": null,
      "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable type: 'String' within parent 'Variety' (/createTransplant/variety/name)"
    },
    {
      "path": [
        "createTransplant",
        "variety",
        "plant"
      ],
      "locations": null,
      "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable type: 'String' within parent 'Variety' (/createTransplant/variety/plant)"
    }
  ]
}

I have looked at a number of seemingly similar issues, but these seem related to recent updates of the amplify cli and how subscriptions are handled.
